# Creating liferay portlet - how to pass data to view.jsp from Java class?

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to create portlet in liferay with just only from a JSP file called `view.jsp`. What I need is:

1. When the portlet loads, I want to call custom Java class where I generate an array.
2. I need to pass that array to the `view.jsp`.

How to do that?

Comment: Just some clarification, do you mean view.jsp? And do you need the value after the page is rendered? If so why?

Comment: Yes I mean jsp. I want to parse remote xml and put all data to array, and then pass this array to view.jsp. I just don't want to write code in jsp itself. I want to use java class.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Have you created your portlet with the `create.sh` script from Liferay? In this case, we will need to create a new portlet class that extends `MVCPortlet`:

```
public class ArrayPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

}
```

Also, you will have to change the `WEB-INF/portlet.xml` file to point to its class. Replace the line below by

```
 <portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>
```

by one naming your portlet class:

```
<portlet-class>br.com.seatecnologia.arrayportlet.ArrayPortlet</portlet-class>
```

This is just setup. Now, the cool part: code! You should create a method for handling the view of the portlet. This method should be named `doView()` and has two parameters: a `RenderRequest` and a `RendertResponse`. Also, it throws some exceptions and delegate the portlet rendering to the superclass method:

```
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
throws IOException, PortletException {
    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

Before rendering the portlet, however, we create our array:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
```

and put it in the `RenderRequest` received as parameter. You should give a name to the parameter - in this case, the name is `"my-array"`:

```
renderRequest.setAttribute("my-array", array);
```

This is our class, complete:

```
public class ArrayPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {
        String[] array = new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
        renderRequest.setAttribute("my-array", array);
        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }
}
```

It is through the `RenderRequest` object that we pass values to the JSP. Now, in the JSP, we should "import" the `RenderRequest` instance (and other objects as well) adding the `<portlet:defineObjects />` tag to the beginning of the JSP. After this, we can get any attribute from the `renderRequest` object through its name. Note that the method `getAttribute()` returns `Object` so you should cast its return value to the correct type:

```
<portlet:defineObjects />
<%
String[] anArrayFromMyPortlet = (String[])renderRequest.getAttribute("my-array");
%>
```

Now, you just use your retrieved object as you wish:

```
<ul>
<% for (String string : anArrayFromMyPortlet) { %>
<li><%= string %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

This is the result of this code in my machine:

[image]

Comment: Using JSTL Core or Core RT taglibs would give you a more elegant solution on your JSP page.

Comment: This is hands down the best liferay tutorial I've ever seen in any subject concerning it. They should hire you to write documentation, tutorials, articles, wikis, demonstrations, books and everything.

Comment: @Nenotlep it's impressive how terrible their documentation is for people new to portlets. 100% agree

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in several ways :

1) You can use  `renderRequest.setAttribute("my-array", array);`

2) You can put your data into a session

`request.getPortletSession().setAttribute("my-array", array);`

In the second case don't forget to delete your element from the session when you don't need it any more.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite vague, I recommend to get some introduction to portlet development as it seems to be about the basic understanding of the infrastructure/specification.

An attempt to answer your question by giving some pointers - apologies if they're also too vague:

- init() is part of the portlet lifecycle and will be called once, when the portlet class is loaded.
- You can pass values to your view by (for example) adding request attributes to your RenderRequest in doView()

of course this varies with the portlet framework that you're using - the methods mentioned above are from the underlying portlet specification (i.e. JSR-286)