# Liferay : How to call a Servlet from a JSP Page

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

This is my first Portlet. I am not getting values inside my servlet. Please, see the program. Inside my custom portlet Java class `doView()` method, I show a JSP page

```
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
throws IOException, PortletException {            
    include(viewJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

Inside the `view.jsp` page, I refer to a servlet to receive the values:

```
<form action="formServlet" method="post">
    <h1>Please Login</h1>
    Login:    <input type="text" name="login"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type=submit value="Login">
</form>
```

Inside `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>formServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FormServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>formServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>formServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Inside my servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {  
    String name = (String)request.getParameter("login");
    System.out.println("The Name is "+name);    
}
```

But I don't know why the servlet is not being called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE**: *This is an answer to a somewhat complicated question. If you are trying to learn the basics of portlet creation, I posted a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894095/creating-liferay-portlet-how-to-pass-data-to-view-jsp-from-java-class/6913341#6913341) in another question.*

---

You are submitting a form using the [POST method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) but your servlet just implements `doGet()`, which serves the GET method. You should either submit your form using GET or implement the `doPost()` method (which would be preferable in other situations).

Also, it is necessary to precede the `<url-pattern>` content by a slash if it is an absolute pattern. That is, it should be

```
<url-pattern>/formServlet</url-pattern>
```

instead of

```
<url-pattern>formServlet</url-pattern>
```

That said, **forget servlets now!**

You are doing it in **one of the worst ways**. It is really a bad idea to write a portlet which calls a servlet. After a long time working with Liferay I can imagine situations where it would be more or less reasonable, but it is not here and will not be most of the times.

So, **what should you do?** You should submit your form to an *action URL*. To do it, first include the `portlet` taglib in your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>
```

Now, **replace** the `action` of your form by the `<portlet:actionURL />`. This tag will be replaced by a special URL generated by the portal. Also, **precede** each input name with the tag `<portlet:namespace />`; your `<input type="text" name="login">` should become `<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace />login">` then. This tag will be replaced by a string which is associated with only your portlet; since you can have a lot of portlets in a page, each input should specify from what portlet it comes from. This is the final result:

```
<form action="<portlet:actionURL />" method="post">
    <h1>Please Login</h1>
    Login:    <input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace />login"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="<portlet:namespace />password"><br>
    <input type=submit value="Login">
</form>
```

Now you are going to submit your data correctly - but **how to get the submitted data?** It certainly is not necessary to use a servlet! Instead, **add** to your custom portlet class a method called `processAction()`. This method should return `void` and receive two parameters, of the time `javax.portlet.ActionRequest` and `javax.portlet.ActionResponse`. This is an example of an empty `processAction()`:

```
public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
    // Nothing to be done for now.
}
```

When a request to an action URL (as the one generated by `<portlet:actionURL />`) is sent to the server, it is firstly processed by the `processAction()` method and then by `doView()`. Therefore, the code you would write in your servlet **should be put** in your `processAction()`. The result should be then:

```
public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
    String name = (String)request.getParameter("login");
    System.out.println("The Name is "+name);
}
```

Try it and you will see that it will work well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious time. could you please tell me <form action="<portlet:actionURL />"  how this will contact to my custom Portlet class written ??

Comment: To contact your custom Portlet class (assuming it extends GenericPortlet or a subclass of it) you need to change the value of the <portlet-class> in your portlet.xml to the package and class name of your custom Portlet class e.g. com.mypackage.MyCustomPortlet

Comment: This is inside my portlet.xml file , <portlet-class>com.test.GreetingPortlet</portlet-class>  , In this class i have several methods as adduser , deleteuser --etc , so it will be <form action="<portlet:actionURL />" method="adduser">   Is this correct ??

Comment: yyy, I've added an answer to this comment below.

Answer (score 2):

yyy - Here's the answer to your comment:

In your JSP page you'll need to add the following for each of the actions you want that portlet to perform:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="addUserURL">
<portlet:param name="<%= ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME %>" value="addUser" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<form method="post" action="<%= addUserURL %>">
```

Then in your com.test.Greeting portlet you'd have for each of these:

```
public void addUser (ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) {}
```

Does this answer your question?

Also it's usually best to start a new question rather than adding a comment.